# Load persistence config file in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data JPA, and have defined the data source, entity manager, and hibernate config in a Java class instead of XML. Here is my class:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.user.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("xxx");
        dataSource.setUsername("xxx");
        dataSource.setPassword("xxx");
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.test.user.repository.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

My question is, do I have to create a bean definition for this config class? How does it get loaded at Application startup? We are not using Spring boot, there is no main method etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can either config it in web.xml or WebApplicationInitializer so once you can set up your root context with your different kind of config file.
see example below

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAppInitializer.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
         rootContext.register(AppConfig.class,PersistenceConfig.class,SecurityConfig.class);
//      rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(MvcConfig.class);

        ...
}
```

Or you can just register just your AppConfig class and set it up to scan the package (com.example.config) where PersistenceConfig located in it will load the configuration bean that annotate with @Configuration.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.example.config","com.example.validator","com.example.service", "com.example.security","com.example.aspect"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties" })

public class AppConfig {
     ....
}
```

Let me know if my answer is not clear, I can detail you more about it.

This link might help you out about the spring web application initialization http://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-vs-java-config